# Is it possible to use Clang libtooling with other compilers?

Tags: visual-c++, clang, libtooling

We have a product which targets a large variety of platforms. Compilation for some of those platforms is using MSVC rather than clang.

We are using the clang libtooling interface where we provide a compile_commands.json file to indicate how to compile each translation unit. How does clang use the provided compile_commands.json information?  Does it use all the flags, but run it through its own compiler?  Is it possible to use libtooling with a compile_commands.json having instructions on MSVC compilation?  Our compile_commands.json for each platform is created by our internal build system, similarly to how cmake would generate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it use all the flags, but run it through its own compiler?

Yes, it runs lexical and syntax analysis just as if you execute `clang` with all these flags directly.

> Is it possible to use libtooling with a compile_commands.json having instructions on MSVS compilation?

Clang can mimic MSVC `cl.exe` when being run as `clang-cl.exe` or passed `--driver-mode=cl` flag. So, if your command line contain `cl.exe` style flags (like `/MD` and `/Z7`), theoretically it should be possible to use libtooling too.